# Does wifi need to be on for AirDrop, even if using ethernet connection?

Tags: network, wifi, imac, airdrop

My iMac is connected to my network with an ethernet cable - as such I have turned wifi off, to ensure that I am using the wired network, rather than the much slower wifi network.

AirDrop never seems to work on that iMac, whereas I can AirDrop easily between my iOS devices and MacBook (which is on wifi).

I have only just clicked that these two points may be related. For AirDrop to work do I need:

- All devices to be connected to the same wifi network?
- Wifi to be switched on, but not connected, on the iMac?
- Something else?

If I need wifi to be enabled on the iMac, can I "forget" my home wireless network without iCloud forgetting it on my other devices?

Comment: I've turned on wifi on my iMac and it is now connected to my network via both ethernet and wifi - with separate IP addresses. It is still not visible to other devices on AirDrop, nor can it see my other devices.

Answer (score 1):

Please turn on wifi on the iMac, but no need to connect to any network. Since you are connected via Ethernet your syncing iMac with iCloud will happen without any interruption. Now you will be able to use Airdrop and iCloud syncing simultaneously. Hopes this will help.

Comment: I think that LC1983 is asking if directing the iMac to forget the WiFi network will cause all other devices sharing the same iCloud Keychain to forget the same network.

Comment: @MicChannel That is correct. Wifi seems to connect to my network automatically. I cad both wired & wireless ip addresses. iPhone still can't see iMac, nor can iMac see iPhone.